# Facing Warning message in Joomla Frontend?

Tags: joomla2.5

Showing warning message when change joomla 1.5 to joomla 2.5+?

```
Warning

JUser: :_load: Unable to load user with ID: 123
```

how can i disable this warning from administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a fake user with that id. Go to phpmyadmin (or your favourite mysql interface) and execute this query:

```
  INSERT INTO jos_users values (123,' newadmin','newadmin','123@example.com','531b5f50f082c59730b3bf7f9c457129:GA8lZqlJVZQbD8GYFGltJGNNIvjmcRcT','Super Administrator',0,1,'','',1,''); 
  INSERT INTO jos_user_usergroup_map values (123,8);
```

Change "jos" with your joomla tables prefix before executing the query.
Then remember to change user password and access level from joomla backend.

Comment: yes, the problem is that you probably created some content with that user and joomla if doesn't find the author give that error. Just create a fake user and it's done.

Comment: Alternatively you can find any reference to that userID in your database replacing it with existing userID